# Selecting a node in Raphael/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, raphael

The following code mostly works (thanks to a good answer a couple of days ago!) all except for the last little bit:

```
things.square[1].node.setAttribute("id","clicker");
$("#clicker").click(function(){
    $("#canvas_things1").fadeOut();
    $("#canvas_things2").fadeIn();
});
```

I think the problem is this line:

```
things.square[1].node.setAttribute("id","clicker");
```

I would have thought that square[1].node would work, but it seems not. Can someone spot what's wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $("document").ready(function() {
        var RM  = Raphael("canvas", 1000, 500);

        var attr = {     // for the visible shapes
            fill: "#bbb",      "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: "#222",    "stroke-width": 0.3,
        };
        var attr2 = {    // for the invisible hovering areas
            fill: "green",     "fill-opacity": 0.0,
            stroke: "red",     "stroke-width": 0,
        };
        var things = {};
        /* Square */    things.square     = [ RM.path("m 154.21525,71.431259 74.32805,0 0,70.496711 -74.32805,0 0,-70.496711 z").attr(attr),
                                              RM.path("m 271.25132,77.933263 58.07304,0 0,56.409037 -58.07304,0 0,-56.409037 z").attr(attr2)   ];
        /* Triangle */  things.triangle   = [ RM.path("m 154.02932,222.44063 36.78089,-58.23641 34.48208,58.2364 -71.26297,1e-5").attr(attr),
                                              RM.path("m 271.25132,165.71032 58.07304,0 0,56.40903 -58.07304,0 0,-56.40903 z").attr(attr2)   ];
        for (var shape in things) {
            shape[0].color = Raphael.getColor();
            (function (shape, sh) {
                shape[1][0].onmouseover = function () {
                    shape[0].animate({fill:shape[0].color, stroke:"#ccc"}, 500);
                    document.getElementById(sh)[0].style.display = "block";
                    shape[0].toFront();   R.safari();
                };
                shape[1][0].onmouseout = function () {
                    shape[0].animate({fill:"#bbb", stroke:"#222"}, 500);
                    document.getElementById(sh)[0].style.display = "none";
                    shape[0].toFront();   R.safari();
                };
            })(things[sh], sh);
        } // end for every member of things

        things.square[1].node.setAttribute("id","clicker");
        $("#clicker").click(function(){
            $("#canvas_things1").fadeOut();
            $("#canvas_things2").fadeIn();
        });

    }); // end the document ready function
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know that it does not work? E.g. do you get an error? If so what does it say? or does it fail silently? If so, what did you expect it to do, that it didn't?

Comment: It just fails silently. I would expect it to cause the current canvas (canvas_things1) to fade out and the other canvas to fade in. Instead nothing happens (the canvas does not fade out).

Comment: Actually it used to work when 'square' was not an array of paths, but instead just a path: things.square = RM.path("..."); and things.square.node.setAttribute("id","clicker");.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using setAttribute with an array of Raphael paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817310/using-setattribute-with-an-array-of-raphael-paths)

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute is set properly.

### **[Try it out with this jQuery (click on the 1st red square)](http://jsfiddle.net/aDREU/)**

Notice, that I had to rip out your `for` loop. This is because the self executing anonymous function was causing a runtime error due to being called with undefined variables.

`sh` is never defined, but it is used here:

```
        })(things[sh], sh);                               // sh is never defined!
    } // end for every member of things
```

I would have replaced the `for` loop but I don't understand what you're trying to do.

At any rate, I would suggest using the Raphael custom event handler `.hover()`.

---

PS: Watch your unnecessary comas (you have 4):

```
    stroke: "#222",    "stroke-width": 0.3,                 // <== Trailing comma
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `things.square` doesn't map to a single element in your SVG when you have multiple paths.  There's two approaches that should work:

1. Loop through each of the path elements in `things.square` and apply the click function to each of them (won't be able to use the `id` attribute then).
2. Use a [group add-on](http://github.com/trotter/raphael-groups) to put all your paths inside a `<g>` element in the SVG, then apply your function to that instead.

Comment: `things.square[1].node` is a single DOM element. That part of the code actually works. The `for` loop doesn't work.